# Convert a searched text to a youtube search link

Tags: c#, youtube

I need to convert the searched text to a youtube search link, for example:

- search text: `the show must go on`
- result: `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=the+show+must+go+on`

And yes, I could "just" write a parser that would replace spaces with the plus sign, but spaces aren't the only thing that are getting replaced, for example:

- search text: `!@#$%^&*()`
- result:  `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()`.

And so manually writing converter for every each special sign would be a really tedious and buggy mess.
   And from what I've seen Youtube API doesn't have anything like that.

**So**, is there a API, dictionary or something else available that could do that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is URL Encoding, right?

```
string searchText ="the show must go on";
string searchUrlBase = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=";
string searchUrl = searchUrlBase + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(searchText);
Console.WriteLine(searchUrl);
```

This will give you `Hello+World` and `!@#$%^&*()` will give you  `!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()`. [Example added here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6aWWNK)